# How to connect metamask to flutter mobile app

Tags: flutter, blockchain, wallet-connect

I want to integrate MetaMask with my flutter mobile application. What package can I use for this purpose?

How can I do this?

I used walltconnect package but through that I was able to call only readable function

I want to call functions from contract both readable and writable functions.